# Was Ignaty Karpezo buried alive and then found alive?

Tags: history, world-war-ii, soviet-union

Wikipedia [claims](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE,_%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) the following. Ignaty Karpezo was a general during WWII. After a heavy bombing he was found without signs of life. A medic determined death. He was buried consequently.

But after a while the unit was visited by the superior ranks. They heard that a general was killed. They said that Soviet generals do not die and ordered to open the grave. Surprisingly Kaprezo was found alive and lived till 1987.

I wonder how and whether it is true.

Comment: Is there an English version of that Wikipedia page? Can you find any other mention of that person or of the claim? Is there a different English spelling of his name? Googling for "Ignaty Kaprezo" (as you have written) brings up only this question in the results.

Answer (score 3):

in "The Bloody Triangle: The Defeat of Soviet Armor in the Ukraine, June 1941"
by Victor Kamenir, you can read in the "Battle of Dubno - June 26-27":

> [image]

Comment: Who did Kamenir cite as the source?